# I have a long time to stay at making some RxJava codes better to average some data

Tags: rx-android, rx-java2

I have a collection of data like dummy below

```
class Place {
     userId,
      price
 }
```

That means a collection of some places.

Use-case:

1. There is a user with userId and login.
2. How to calc average place-price that equal to userId ?
3. RxJava is nice and I have tried `filter` and  `toList`, however it is not so performance nice.

   ```
   Observable.fromIterable(places)
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
             .filter(new Predicate<Place>() {
                 @Override
                 public boolean test(Place place) throws Exception {
                     return place.userId == global.login.userId;
                 }
             })
             .toList()
             .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
             .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Place>>() {
                 @Override
                 public void accept(List<Place> filteredPlace) throws Exception {
                  //Here I have to use loop to do math-average, it is not nice to average.

                 }
             });
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `places` is something that is already available in-memory, you can rearrange the evaluation such as this:

```
Observable.just(places)
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
   .map((Iterable<Place> list) -> {
       double sum = 0.0;
       int count = 0;
       for (Place p : list) {
           if (p.userId == global.login.userId) {
               sum += p.price;
               count++;
           }
       }
       return sum / count;
   })
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(average -> { /* display average */ });
```

If the sequence of `places` becomes available over time (through an `Observable`):

```
Observable<Place> places = ...
places
   .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
   .filter((Place p) -> p.userId == global.login.userId)
   .compose(o -> MathObservable.averageDouble(o.map(p -> p.price)))
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(average -> { /* display average */ });
```

`MathObservable` is part of the [RxJava 2 Extensions](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#mathematical-operations-over-numerical-sequences) library.

Comment: I think your first codes are just call loop as well. Do you think without extensions there's no way to write only in one line ?

Comment: RxJava is a composition library where the tools are distributed within and sometimes outside of it. Usually there is no one liner that solves a non-trivial business case. Since you are on Android, you don't have first-hand access to Java Streams and any Java Streams backport requires an external dependency.